# MacBook Air M1: Noticeable desktop swiping lag

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake, trackpad, desktop, multi-touch

Mac: MacBook Air (M1,2020)

OS: macOS Big Sur (11.4)

Age: ~6-7 months

I'm facing a problem where there seems to be a slight lag when I 4-finger swipe between windows/desktops. It's like a second long & is noticeable. Doesn't happen on multiple swipes.

I noticed this a few weeks ago and closed a few apps-didn't help. So, I shut it down and turned it on again which helped and the lag's gone. I don't shut down my Mac often (mostly just put it to sleep by pressing the power button and esc key).
It reappeared again for the last few days so I shut it down and it's gone. Works instantaneously.

Problem kept reappearing so I updated my Mac to 11.4 but it still occurs after not being shut-down for a while.

Since the problem usually appears after putting the Mac to sleep, I don't think it has to do with the trackpad or any hardware functionality in particular.

[There's also infrequent problems of Safari reloading at times saying websites are very heavy. Once an app or two crashed on me but I didn't think it was a big problem since I figured it's just apps not optimised for M1 but I thought I'd add this in case it's part of some bigger problem]

(I'm sure this doesn't happen with MacBooks since it didn't on my previous MacBook Air(2015) & since this is much faster, I definitely didn't expect this kinda problem here.)

Comment: Experiencing the same thing. Did you maybe figure it out?

Answer (score 1):

Probably it's because of some third-party software with access to screen recording.

Try to close any unused programs and check again. In my case, the lag was caused by Zoom.